# Deserialise Nested JSON with JSON Utility Unity 5.4

Tags: c#, unity, json

This is what my JSON looks like: {"series":[{,"points":[{"ts":"1473850836254","value":"11.27"},{"ts":"1473851256637","value":"6.44"}]}]}

I am trying to access the values in "points" by calling something like: ***data.series.points[0].ts***

```
    Void Start(){
    IncomingData data = IncomingData.CreateFromJSON(jsonResponse.text);
    print("Series point length" + data.series.points.Count);
    print("Series point 0" + data.series.points.get_Item[0].ts); // error
    }
```

//----------------------------------------- classes -------------------------

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class IncomingData
    {
        public Series series;
        public static IncomingData CreateFromJSON(string json)
        {   
            return JsonUtility.FromJson<IncomingData>(json);
         }
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class Series
    {
        public List<Points> points = new List<Points> { };
    }


    [System.Serializable]
    public class Points
    {
        public int ts;
        public int value;
    }
```

My error:

// error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type `method group'

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please don't edit your questions in a way which makes the posted answers nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you want to use `data.series.points[0].ts` but then you... don't, you use `data.series.points.get_Item[0].ts`

The thing you say you want to use works perfectly fine so let's dig into why the other thing is not working:

- `get_Item` is a function, not a field or property. So you need to call it with `(0)` and not with `[0]`
- `get_Item` is a magical function that should *never ever* be called directly. There is a special error for it as well (CS0571, "cannot explicitly call operator or accessor").
- `get_Item` is called if you use the syntax `points[0]`, the *compiler* translates this to `.get_Item(0)` so you can use the neat looking fancy syntax and not worry about anything.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the syntax problem! I have updated it - but my question still stands: Lovely JSONUtility tells me my Series object is Unexpected Node/ then Null and _data.series.points[0].ts_ isoutofrange ....

Comment: @BonnieB, if your question still stands, how has this answered your question? **Do not accept an answer if your question has not been answered**. Reposting to continue your question just leads to downvotes and an eventual question ban.

Comment: Look at the content, he has a new question about the same code